# Strange behavior with SQL server IN clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am wondering why the below SQL statement behaves the way that it does:

```
select * 
from tableA 
where document_id in (select document_id
                      from  tableB 
                      where batch_id = 99997)
```

`tableA` contains the column `document_id` but `tableB` does not, so the query appears to return all rows in `tableA`, this behavior occurs if you use any field name in the select statement of the IN clause that is a field in `tableA`.  Using a name not in `tableA` or `tableB` does result in an error.

Comment: Not strange at all, [this is by (flawed) design](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/298674) and won't be fixed, however it has been reported as a bug about a dozen times. See http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187638.aspx http://connect.microsoft.com/SQL/feedback/details/338468 http://connect.microsoft.com/SQL/feedback/details/302281 http://connect.microsoft.com/SQL/feedback/details/542289 http://connect.microsoft.com/SQL/feedback/details/735178 http://connect.microsoft.com/SQL/feedback/details/786947 http://connect.microsoft.com/SQL/feedback/details/499463 362016 624370 etc etc

Answer (score 5):

It's not an error. In a subquery, you can still use columns form the parent. So when you say

```
SELECT document_id FROM tableB WHERE batch_id = 99997
```

You are saying for every row where `batch_id` is 9997 in tableB, select `document_id` from `tableA`. And of course, all those `document_id` values exists, so it will return all those rows.

Answer (score 3):

This is why I'd suggest you get in the habit of putting the explicit table name for each column. It is also helpful for maintainability or later extending queries.

```
select * 
from tableA A
where A.document_id in (select B.document_id
                  from  tableB B
                  where B.batch_id = 99997)
```

If you qualify the tables like this, it will throw a clear error on runtime and prevent any subtle mistakes. This would give the error similar to

> tableB.document_id does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

I've just found this behaviour myself after many years.  I use Exists() instead of the IN() clause except for ad-hoc and non data modifying queries because of unexpected results in the past with null values, but this had me flummoxed until I read DavidG's response.  There is no reason to write a query in such a manner, referencing an outer column without referencing the subqueries table at all but a syntax checker would have trouble disallowing it.

Mostly if using IN() with a sub query you would be referencing a foreign key which, 95+% of the time (with our company standards), has the same name as the primary key, but those 5% of times could catch you out.

Although it seems this behavior also occurs with Exists()...

```
Select * from tableA Where Exists(Select document_id from tableB)
```

...Exists() is never written this way because it makes no sense but is written more explicitly something like...

```
Select * From tableA Where Exists(Select * from tableB tB where tB.TableB_Document_id = tableA.document_id)
```

and so less likely to occur.

(Note: I would've put this in a comment but I don't have the points)

Comment: If you don't have the rep to leave comments, you should look to answer questions not requiring clarifications or ask your own questions. Not **abuse** other mechanisms of SO. If we wanted low rep users to be able to comment, they'd have that ability. You're not going to *earn* rep by doing things like this.

Comment: As said, this is a comment, not an answer. StackOverflow isn't a forum. Take the [tour]: "Ask questions, get answers, no distractions"

Comment: @CertainPerformance.  Although this is only the 2nd time I've replied in SO I use it often for finding solutions to problems or as code reminders.  Often the useful bit of info is not a direct answer but buried in a comment. I do understand the need for strictures lest useful replies get lost in waffle, as long as the strictures use one sense of the word and are not driven by the other.  Perhaps my biggest mistake was mentioning at the end that i would have put it in comment if I could, because arsebin3 answer is also effectively a comment in much the same vein as mine.